# COALESCE function won't return CHAR(1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

Using `COALESCE` function but getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'X' to data type int.

I have to join two tables on two conditions. I want that if the second condition doesn't hold but there is a blank cell (not null but blank '') in Table 1 then to join to that row. If the second condition doesn't hold then to return a zero.

Join Table 1 and Table 2 - return Table 2 and column 3 from Table 1.

Table 1

```
(A, 1, X),
(A, 2, Y),
(A, 3, Z),
(A, , X),
(B, 1, X),
(B, 2, Z),
(B, 3, Y),
```

Table 2

```
(A, 1),
(A, 2),
(A, 3),
(A, 5),
(B, 1),
(B, 2),
(B, 3),
(B, 5)
```

I want to get a return of

```
(A, 1, X),
(A, 2, Y),
(A, 3, Z),
(A, 5, X),
(B, 1, X),
(B, 2, Z),
(B, 3, Y),
(B, 5, NULL)
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (letter1 CHAR(1), num1 INT, letter2 CHAR(1))  
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (letter1 CHAR(1), num1 INT)  

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES    
('A', 1, 'X'),  
('A', 2, 'Y'),  
('A', 3, 'Z'),  
('A', null, 'X'),  
('B', 1, 'X'),  
('B', 2, 'Y'),  
('B', 3, 'Z')  

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES 
('A', 1),  
('A', 2),  
('A', 3),  
('A', 5),  
('B', 1),  
('B', 2),    
('B', 3),  
('B', 5) 

SELECT t2.*,   
    COALESCE(  
        (SELECT TOP 1 letter2 FROM @table1 WHERE letter1 = t2.letter1 AND num1 = t2.num1),   
        (SELECT TOP 1 letter2 FROM @table1 WHERE letter1 = t2.letter1 AND num1 IS NULL),   
        0  
    ) AS missing_letter  
FROM @table2 t2
```

Comment: show your code too

Comment: You are calling `COALESCE` on two `CHAR(1)` and a *number*. If you want to return `'0'` use that  instead of 0. If you want a NULL don't specify a third option

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need :

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 outer apply
    ( select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 in ('', t2.col2)
      order by t2.col2 desc
    ) t2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this has less to do with `coalesce()` and more to do with the `join`s:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.letter2, t1def.letter2) as letter2
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.letter1 = t1.letter1 and t2.num1 = t1.num1 left join
     table1 t1def
     on t2.letter1 = t1def.letter1 and t1def.num1 is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is your datatype. `COALESCE` is short hand for a `CASE` expression. For example. `COALESCE('a',1,'c')` would be short hand for:

```
CASE WHEN 'a' IS NOT NULL THEN 'a'
     WHEN 1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
     ELSE 'c'
END
```

The Documentation ([COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) describes this as well:

> The `COALESCE` expression is a syntactic shortcut for the `CASE`
>   expression. That is, the code `COALESCE(expression1,...n)` is
>   rewritten by the query optimizer as the following `CASE` expression:
>
> ```
> CASE  
> WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1  
> WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2  
> ...  
> ELSE expressionN  
> END
> ```

A `CASE` expression follows [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and `int` has a **higher** datatype precedence than `varchar`; thus everything will implicit cast to an `int`. This is why both the `COALESCE` and `CASE` expression will fail, because neither `'a'` or `'c'` can be converted to an `int`.

You'll need to therefore explicitly `CONVERT` your `int` to a `varchar`:

```
COALESCE('a',CONVERT(char(1),1),'c')
```

The documentation (cited above), however, also goes to state:

> This means that the input values *(expression1, expression2,
>   expressionN, etc.)* are evaluated multiple times. Also, in compliance
>   with the SQL standard, a value expression that contains a subquery is
>   considered non-deterministic and the subquery is evaluated twice. In
>   either case, different results can be returned between the first
>   evaluation and subsequent evaluations.
>
> For example, when the code `COALESCE((subquery), 1)` is executed, the
>   subquery is evaluated twice. As a result, you can get different
>   results depending on the isolation level of the query. For example,
>   the code can return `NULL` under the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level in a
>   multi-user environment. To ensure stable results are returned, use the
>   `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` isolation level, or replace `COALESCE` with the
>   `ISNULL` function.

Considering you are using a subquery, a (nested) `ISNULL` might be the better choice here.

*It's worth noting, as people seem to confuse them as they are functionally similar, but `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` do not behave the same. `COALESCE` uses Data Type precedence, however, `ISNULL` implicitly casts the second value to whatever the datatype of the first paramter is. Thus `ISNULL('a',1)` works fine, but `COALESCE('a',1)` does not.*

Answer (score 1):

Just change the zero to a null. You can't mix datatypes in a coalesce:

```
SELECT t2.*,
COALESCE(
(SELECT TOP 1 letter2 FROM @table1 WHERE letter1 = t2.letter1 AND num1 = t2.num1),
(SELECT TOP 1 letter2 FROM @table1 WHERE letter1 = t2.letter1 AND num1 IS NULL),
null
) AS missing_letter
FROM @table2 t2
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't see that.

Comment: The last parameter with ', null' is actually superfluous. The coalesce would return null anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The query works if the 0 in the COALESCE is replaced by '0'.
That way the COALESCE doesn't contain mixed data types.

```
SELECT t2.*,
    COALESCE(  
        (SELECT TOP 1 letter2 FROM @table1 t1 WHERE t1.letter1 = t2.letter1 AND t1.num1 = t2.num1),   
        (SELECT TOP 1 letter2 FROM @table1 t1 WHERE t1.letter1 = t2.letter1 AND t1.num1 IS NULL),   
        '0'
    ) AS missing_letter  
FROM @table2 t2
ORDER BY t2.letter1, t2.num1;
```

And you can avoid having to retrieve data from table1 twice.
By using an OUTER APPLY.

Since the expected results has a NULL for ('B',5), the COALESCE isn't even needed this way.

```
SELECT t2.letter1, t2.num1, t1.letter2 AS missing_letter
FROM @table2 AS t2
OUTER APPLY (
   select top 1 t.letter2
   from @table1 AS t
   where t.letter1 = t2.letter1 
     and (t.num1 is null or t.num1 = t2.num1)
   order by t.num1 desc
) AS t1
ORDER BY t2.letter1, t2.num1;
```

**Result:**

```
letter1 num1    missing_letter
------- ----    --------------
A       1       X
A       2       Y
A       3       Z
A       5       X
B       1       X
B       2       Y
B       3       Z
B       5       NULL
```

Comment: Sorting by t.num1 to get the Top 1 makes the OUTER APPLY solution a lot more expensive.

Comment: @cloudsafe Well, I guess it should be benchmarked on a large dataset. But it's required when only 1 outer apply is used. So that those with matching num1 get listed first for the top 1. But unless proven wrong, I think it'll be fast enough.